# Programmatically concatenate mp4 files

Tags: c, video, mp4

I have two MP4 files, say,

1. mp4 (20 secs) and
2. mp4 (20 secs);

both are generated by the same application. I want to concatenate them programmatically. I've read the ISO/IEC 14496-12 documentation and googled some possible answers but there're only a few.

From what I have read so far, the files can be concatenated if I concatenate the MDAT part and merge the elements of the STBL box such as STTS, STSS, STSC, STSZ, STCO, etc.

I've tried using the strategy mentioned above, I edited the duration part in MVHD and MDHD, concatenated others boxes as below and output as a new mp4 file.

```
MDAT part of 1.mp4 -- MDAT part of 2.mp4 -- MOOV box (MOOV, MVHD, TRAK, MDIA, STBL, etc)
```

Inside the STBL box, I concatenated the elements in two files, I use the same structure for audio and video parts:

```
STTS(1.mp4) -- STTS(2.mp4) -- STSS(1.mp4) -- STSS(2.mp4) -- STSC(1.mp4) -- STSC(2.mp4) -- STSZ(1.mp4) -- STSZ(2.mp4) -- STCO(1.mp4) -- STCO(2.mp4)
```

However, the output file cannot be played or opened.

If I simply concatenated the TRAK boxes of the two files, such as:

```
MOOV (MVHD -- TRAK (and all other boxes of 1.mp4) -- TRAK (and all other boxes of 1.mp4))
```

I can get the output file play, but the duration stays the same as 1.mp4...

Any suggestions or concrete examples about which parts I should edit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, to programmatically concatenate 2 mp4 files you need to be sure that both files contain the same audio and video codecs.

You need to check the audio track and the video track and compare the codec types. For example, if one file video codec is H.264 and the other file video codec is H.263 then those two can't be concatenated. Audio track may also have different codecs (e.g amr, aac).

Since you wrote that both files were created with the same application, it might be ok to assume that both use the same audio and video codecs.
In order to concatenate them, it is true that the `mdat` atom data of the second file can be concatenated to the `mdat` atom data of the first file. Then the `mdat` atom size should be updated to represent sum of both `mdat` atoms sizes.

As for other atoms, there is no easy way to handle them. For example, for `stco` atom, which represents the chunks offsets, you'll need to add all the offsets of the second file audio/video samples (there is an `stco` atom per audio/video track). Yet those audio/video samples changed their offsets when added to the first file so you'll need to calculate the new offsets for each chunk. Other atoms will need to be changed too. e.g. the `stsz` which contains the number of samples and their sizes.

In the `stss` atom you'll need to update the overall number of keyframes and add all the second file keyframes, but each sample number of the second file will have to be changed (you'll need to add to it the number of key-frames of the first file).

You need to go over the ISO/IEC 14496-12 documentation and handle each atom according to the specification.

Comment: @VC.One any idea what to do if stco stsz stts and stsc are all 0? I have this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/76005354/play-concatenated-mp4-file

Comment: @anthnyprschka No worries, **It is normal** for those atoms to have "zero" entries. It just signals to an MPEG decoder to expect the next following MP4 bytes to be in a  **fragmented mode** (_ie:_ the decoder must ignore some parts of the global MOOV header and instead it must check for such details in a new MOOF atom regularly as things might change per chunk, such as each chunk's time length, etc). **PS:** They are "zero" because the idea is that they are naturally unknown. How can you know a bytes position that wont exist until minutes in the future of some dynamically generated livestream?